# Sharepoint 2013 Alerts are not firing any mails for the Normal Alerts and search Alerts, can someone guide me with the Email configuration for Alerts?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alert, 2013

i've been working with SharePoint alerts for the past two months and in SharePoint 2010 for all the alerts i setup, i recieved confirmation mail and alert mails regarding to the context for both List/Library alerts and search alerts.

but in Sharepoint 2013 RTM Enterprise, I have configured the mail as in 2010 but i do not recieve any confirmation mails or alert mails for the alerts i have set up. i followed the msdn guide to setup but unfortuantely it hasn't been working.

Is there any other configurations other than the configuration of the outgoing mail service that has to be done inorder to get the mail service?

Comment: Here is some stuff to try: http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2009/11/20/alerts-in-sharepoint-troubleshooting-moss-wss.aspx?PageIndex=3#comments